# error while relaese android react native apk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have various problems in relaese apk build. At the moment I solved it by renaming all the library packages and consequently all the imports that give me problems. But I need an idea not to do this every time. Do you have any solutions about it?

The errors if I don't rename the libraries are:

```
C:\Users\manue\OneDrive\Desktop\MyApp\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\build.transforms\9166b1d6d34e6b3b03f3d84907b6a605\transformed\classes\classes.dex, C:\Users\manue\OneDrive\Desktop\MyApp\android\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\mergeExtDexRelease\classes2.dex
```

other 7 libraries also give me these errors:

react-native-async-storage-async
react-native-sound
react-native-background-timer
react-native-device-info
react-native-splash-screen
react-native-google-signin
react-native-community-netinfo

Comment: Doing a ```clean project``` or ```./gradlew clean``` usually helps with errors like these. You will have to post the complete error log if you need more help diagnosing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to build.gradle app module solved my problem

```
android{
defaultConfig {

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
dependencies {
//...
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```